# Jquery not working with phoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I am using phonegap, and this code loads perfectly in my android mobile.But When i click the button it does not shows the text.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("#test1").text("Hello world!");
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p id="test1"></p>
<button id="btn1">Set Text</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try using `.on('click tap', function(){...});` - since you're not clicking on a mobile device, you're tapping.

Comment: change the order of cordova js and jquery js....load jQuery first and then load PhoneGap

Comment: save jquery localy and try

Comment: Is JQuery even being loaded? As your src href starts with '//' doesn't that mean the request will be file:// ? (As that is where index.html is being loaded from inside your WebView)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that JQuery is being loaded into the page.

You have referenced it as

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
```

which says use whatever protocol the current page is being server from. On a mobile device you are being served from file:// so the actual request the browser makes to fetch the script is:

```
file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
```

You need to specify the scheme you want to use or else include it in the PG project itself.

Answer (score 1):

When working with mobile devices, it is greatly recommended that you use the mobile version of jquery, `jquery.mobile.js`

Then you can use [vclick](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html) and everything works fine:

> Normalized event for handling touchend or mouse click events on touch
>   devices.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#btn1").vclick(function(){
       $("#test1").text("Hello world!");
     });
});
```

Comment: hi "use the mobile version of jquery" first understand jquerymobile in not mobile version of  jquery  ,"  A unified, HTML5-based user interface system for all popular mobile device platforms, built on the rock-solid jQuery and jQuery UI foundation. Its lightweight code is built with progressive enhancement, and has a flexible, easily themeable design." http://jquerymobile.com/

Comment: @ArjunTRaj It's a touch-optimized JavaScript library made by the jQuery team. It makes use of features from jQuery and jQuery UI, so you can extend what you were doing on top of your already existing jQuery code. Whether to call it a "full framework" or just an extension of jQuery is just a matter of technicality.

Comment: @|46kok that i know but , jqm is not "the mobile version of jquery"

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
     $(document).on('pageinit', function(event){
        $("#btn1").click(function(){
            $("#test1").text("Hello world!");
        });
     });
  </script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
   <p id="test1"></p>
   <button id="btn1">Set Text</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Instead of `doc ready` use `pageinit` of jQuerymobile if developing for mobile apps.